# Proving $u\mapsto |u|^2u$ is Lipschitz on bounded subsets of $H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega).$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm [reading a paper][1]<sup>1</sup> and am stumped verifying two details.

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with smooth boundary. I'd like to show that the map $u\mapsto |u|^2u$ is

1. a map from $H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$ to itself.
2. Lipschitz on every bounded subset of $H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$.

The paper establishes as lemmas that

1. If $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ and $||u||_{H^1}\le 1$, then $||u||_{\infty}\lesssim 1+\sqrt{\log(1+||u||_{H^2})}$
2. $|||u|^2u||_{H^2}\lesssim ||u||_{\infty}^2||u||_{H^2}$ for $u\in H^2(\Omega)$.

Combining the two lemmas makes it easy to see that if $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ then $|u|^2u\in H^2(\Omega)$. If $u\in H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $\phi_n\in C_0^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ are such that $||\phi_n-u||_{H^1}\to 0$, it would suffice to show that $|||\phi_n|^2\phi_n-|u|^2u||_{H^1}\to 0$, but I don't know how to go about showing this.

Thanks for your help!

<sup>1</sup>*Brézis, Haïm; Gallouet, T.*, [**Nonlinear Schrödinger evolution equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0362-546X(80)90068-1), Nonlinear Anal., Theory Methods Appl. 4, 677-681 (1980). [ZBL0451.35023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0451.35023).
[1]: https://www.i2m.univ-amu.fr/perso/thierry.gallouet/art.d/brezisgallouet.pdf

Comment: Are you asking how to show the last convergence?

Comment: And could you write down the norm?

Comment: Link/reference to the paper, please.

Comment: What is $\lesssim$? Is this binary relation just meant to imply that $(\lesssim)=(\leq C)$? Binary relations in cited lemmas cannot hold as inequalities $\forall\,u,\,\forall\,\Omega$ with constants $C=1$.

Comment: I added the link. Thanks again!

Comment: The link in the post seems to be dead - I guess the paper in question might be this one: https://www.i2m.univ-amu.fr/perso/thierry.gallouet/art.d/brezisgallouet.pdf (Nonlinear Schroedinger Evolution Equations by Brezis and Gallouet).

Answer (score 1):

All spaces are assumed complex, so $|u|^2u$ cannot be replaced by $u^3$. Your difficulties with convergence come from inappropriate definition of sequence $\{\phi_n\}$ — it must be a sequence convergent in $H^2(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega)$. To show that $|u|^2u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, there is more elegant way. Take an alternative equivalent definition 
$$
H^1_0(\Omega)=\{w\in H^1(\Omega)\,\colon\; w|_{\partial\Omega}=0\}=
\overline{C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)}^{H^1(\Omega)}
$$
and consider the trace of $\,|u|^2u\,$ on $\,\partial\Omega\,$ with $\,|u|^2u\in H^2(\Omega)\subset C(\overline{\Omega})$. Since $\, u|_{\partial\Omega}=0\,$ implies 
$\, (|u|^2u)|_{\partial\Omega}=0$, one concludes that $\,|u|^2u\in H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$.
To show that the mapping 
$$
\,L\colon H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)\to H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)\,\tag{$\ast$}
$$
where $\,L(u)\overset{\rm def}{=}|u|^2u$, is Lipschitz  on every bounded
set in $H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$, notice that
\begin{align*}
L(u)-L(v)=|u|^2u-|v|^2v= (u-v)\!\cdot\!|v|^2+(|u|^2-|v|^2)\!\cdot\!v\\
=(u-v)\!\cdot\!|v|^2+(u_1^2+u_2^2-v_1^2-v_2^2)\!\cdot\!v
=(u-v)\!\cdot\!|v|^2+(u_1-v_1)\!\cdot\!(u_1+v_1)\!\cdot\!v\\
+(u_2-v_2)\!\cdot\!(u_2+v_2)\!\cdot\!v
\end{align*}
where $\,u=u_1+iu_2\,$ and $\,v=v_1+iv_2\,$ with 
$$
u,v\in B_M\overset{\rm def}{=}\{w\in H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)\,\colon\; 
\|w\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\leqslant M\},\quad M>0.
$$
Applying to the second order derivatives of products the Leibnitz rule along with the appropriate estimates for embeddings of $\,H^2(\Omega)\,$ into $\,W^{1,p}(\Omega)\,$ and 
$\,C(\overline{\Omega})$, *i.e.*, following basically the way the two lemmas are being proved, one readily finds that
$$
\|L(u)-L(v)\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\leqslant CM^2\|u-v\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\quad\forall\, 
u,v\in B_M\tag{$\ast\ast$}
$$ 
with some constant $C>0$ depending only on domain $\Omega$.  Inequality 
$(\ast\ast)$ implies that the nonlinear mapping $(\ast)$ is Lipschitz on every bounded
set in $H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$, Q.E.D.

Comment: First off, thank you so much for your attention to my question. I'll have more comments once I absorb your strategy. Until then - I have to inquire what you meant on Line 3 instead of $H^1(\Omega)\cap H^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: Now a question of mild substance: I still can't figure out the conclusion from your hint. If you have time, would you care to elucidate the remaining piece of the argument? I'd be overjoyed to accept your answer when I see this.

Comment: Hi @mkl314; I should have clarified. I understood the first part of your comment, I was struggling more with proving the Lipschitz bound from your expression of $L(u)-L(v)$. Even in handling the first order terms I'm left to handle terms like $||\partial_xu||_{\infty}$, which Sobolev embedding isn't equipped to handle since we're in 2D. Provided you have time, could you clarify the conclusion of that part.

Comment: @user135671: No need to handle terms like $\|\partial_x u\|_{L^{\infty}}$. You need the embedding of $H^2(\Omega)$ to the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$  valid for any $p\in (2,\infty)$ since your domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is bounded. For the first order terms, you get \begin{align*}\|\partial_x u\partial_x(|v|^2)\|^2_{L^2}= \|\partial_x u\partial_x(v_1^2+v_2^2)\|_{L^2}\leqslant C_1\bigl\|\partial_x u\!\cdot\!|v|\!\cdot\!|\partial_x v|\bigr\|^2_{L^2}\\ \leqslant C_1\|v\|^2_{L^{\infty}}\|\partial_x u\|^2_{L^4}\|\partial_x v\|^2_{L^4}\leqslant C_2 \|v\|^4_{H^2}\|u\|^2_{H^2}\end{align*}

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I agree that this method works for the first order terms. Regrettably, for the second order terms this doesn't seem to work for me. For example, you see terms like $||(\partial_{xx}u_1+\partial_{xx}v_1)(u_1-v_1)v||_2$ showing up. But now we can't put this into L4, L4, L$\infty$ anymore, since we can't control the fourth powers of the second derivatives. If we try to put it in 2$, \infty,\infty$, then we cant bound it in terms of the difference of u-v in H^2. I meant to write this as a comment to @mkl314

Comment: @user135671: The option $2,\infty,\infty$ will do by virtue of the embedding of 
$H^2(\Omega)$ into $C(\overline{\Omega})$. Namely, $$ \|(\partial_{xx}u_1+
\partial_{xx}v_1)(u_1-v_1)v\|_{L^2}\leqslant C\|u_1+v_1\|_{H^2}\|u_1-v_1\|_{H^2}
\|v\|_{H^2}\leqslant 2M^2C\|u-v\|_{H^2}$$ where an obvious inequality 
$$ |\partial_{xx}(u_1-v_1)|\leqslant |\partial_{xx}(u-v)|$$ has been employed.